# Redirect on extension plugin with onExtensionBeforeInstall

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, extensions, ajax, redirect

i've created an extension plugin and i'am having issue to redirect on the trigger *onExtensionBeforeInstall*

Here is my code :

```
class plgExtensionExample extends JPlugin{

    function onExtensionBeforeInstall($method, $type, $manifest, $eid){
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php'));
        $app->close();
    }
}
```

When i try to install a plugin a have a javascript error :

**In chrome**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of undefined
```

**In firefox**

```
TypeError: res.data is undefined
```

I've searched in joomla and `res` is the result of a call in ajax, but `res` need to be an object and it's a string of html.
I've tried to reach the url which is called in ajax but i got this message :

```
The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again.
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect to the base URL before an extension is installed?

Comment: I want to do a check before installing a plugin, and in some cases i don't want to install the plugin

Comment: Is this check for your own plugin, or other plugins being installed on your site?

Comment: For the the other plugins

Answer (score -1):

Try removing this line;

```
$app->close();
```

Comment: I've already tried and I got the same error.
It's the same when I try to `exit` or `die()`